# Hibernate cascade type with OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have OneToMany relationship between the Order class and Address class. One address can have many orders but one order is only for one address.

Order class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer orderId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.???})
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Address shippingAddress;
    //other fields, getters, setters
}
```

Address class

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "contact_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer contactId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shippingAddress", cascade = {CascadeType.???})
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();
    //other fields, getters, setters
}
```

So, in that case:`@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY); @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shippingAddress", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE/PERSIST/REFRESH})` when I try to create order with address not saved in db I 
catch `TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : store.entity.Order.shippingAddress -> store.entity.Address`.

In other case, when I add `CascadeType.MERGE/PERSIST/REFRESH` to `Order` class I catch `PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: store.entity.Address`.

And of course, if order was deleted, address won't be deleted.

Hope you understand me :)

Comment: Did you set shippingAddress before save?

Comment: @CristianoBombazar Yes, I did